# common-data maven project needs to be included in two spring boot application

Tags: spring-boot

i have three projects 
common-data : separate maven java project
application-1 : spring boot app
application-2: spring boot app

i want to include that common data project in both application-and application-2 as dependency.
but when i am adding that dependency in application-1 spring boot project is started but not running .

http://localhost:8090/hello this is end point: when included dependency of common data in any of application i am getting 404 found error.

```
<dependencies>

    <!-- Add typical dependencies for a web application -->
    <!-- Adds Tomcat and Spring MVC, along others -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

<dependency>
        <groupId>org.stocksrin</groupId>
        <artifactId>stocksrin-common</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
</dependency>


</dependencies>
```

now this is not working

Answer (score 0):

You can do this way:

Step 1: Edit dependency org.stocksrin:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.stocksrin</groupId>
        <artifactId>stocksrin-common</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <systemPath>${basedir}/lib/stocksrin-common.jar</systemPath>
</dependency>
```

**${basedir} : PROJECT ROOT FOLDER**

Step 2: you can set 'includeSystemScope' to true:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <configuration>
    <includeSystemScope>true</includeSystemScope>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: ${basedir} : PROJECT ROOT FOLDER is project dir e.g \demo?

Comment: The dir will contain stocksrin-common.jar when you build stocksrin-common project.